# List of byte to pointers in Delphi

Tags: .net, delphi, pointers

I have this sample in vb.net I need the same output in Delphi. its basically a list of pointers each pointer should point to an array of bytes (a image).

```
        Dim pPointerArray As IntPtr() = New IntPtr(count) {}
        Dim i = 0
        For Each r In ImageList
            pPointerArray(i) = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(r.Images.Length)
            Marshal.Copy(r.Images, 0, pPointerArray(i), r.Images.Length - 1)
            i += 1
        Next
```

I tried many different ways to convert it, none of that seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `ImageList` is. It doesn't appear to be the WinForms control of that name. Assuming you know how to do the `Marshal.Copy` part then you want something like this:

```
var
  PointerArray: array of Pointer;
.....
SetLength(PointerArray, ImageList.Count);
for i := 0 to ImageList.Count-1 do
begin
  PointerArray[i] := GetMem(ImageList[i].Size);
  // copy contents of i-th image to PointerArray[i]
end;
```

Comment: PointerArray[i] := GetMem(ImageList[i].Size);
gives me 'invalid types'

Comment: @Ezi Well, I'm guessing what `ImageList[i]` is. I have absolutely no idea. You didn't tell us that. You asked how to create an array of pointers. If you want to supply more details then I can help more. This is pretty basic stuff though and you really need to be learn how to understand compiler errors yourself. I imagine that `Size` is the pixel dimension of the image. Anyway, view the code above as an outline. It's really down to you to fill in the details.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell that. ImageList is a TStream that contains a list of records each record has a 'array of byte'

Comment: OK, but my advice stands. You can surely work it out from here right?